# printf string exploit returning unexpected hex

Tags: string-formatting, reverse-engineering, overwrite

I'm just starting to get into reverse engineering and I came across a video by live overflow showcasing string format exploits using printf. I tried to reproduce his results but with no luck. My code is the same as in his video. I used radare2 to find the address of my target variable.

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WvrSfcdq1I

radare2 output:
[radare2 command prompt output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgI8w.png)

myCode:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int overwritten;

void vuln(char *sdf) {
    printf("typed stuff! -> ");
    printf(sdf);

    if(overwritten) {
        printf("\nyou overwrote the var!");
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vuln(argv[1]);
}
```

The part I'm having trouble with is at 7:54 in his video. He runs the program with a python script printing `'AAAA' + the variable address + 'bbbb' + '%x ' * 200`. The output in his video is the variable's address surrounded by 41414141 and 42424242. This is the output I observe-> [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqSEx.png). Why don't I even see the 41s and 42s?

Comment: feel free to ask reverse engineering questions on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you! I will look into that.